# how to check an existing node and its contains in an xml file using xslt and differenciate the node by an id number

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Is there any possibility to check if it exists a duplicate node in an xml file, then check the contains of this node and if possible differenciate the both node by an Id number using xslt?
I have for example this xml file

```
<Racine>
  <el1>
   <fils1>context1</fils1>
   <fils2>test1</fils2>
   <fils1>context1</fils1>
  </el1>
  <el2>
   <fils1>context2</fils1>
   <fils2>test2</fils2>
   <fils1>context2</fils1>
  </el2>
  <el3>...........<el3>
</Racine>
```

In this case for example, the node "**fils1**" appears twice in the node "**el1**" and the contains of each of them is the same. I need in this case to transform my xml file so that this node will become

```
<fils1 id=1>context1</fils1>.
```

I add automatically an Id-number to differenciate the both node with the same name and same contain. And when the node got the same name with different contains( also a space in the contain of the node has to be considered as a difference), then lets the node as they are.
How can i make this possible using XSLT? Could someone here help me to transform that?
Thanks a lot for your help.
Franky

Thanks for yours remarks. Here is the expected output:

```
<Racine>
  <el1>
   <fils1 id=1>context1</fils1>
   <fils2>test1</fils2>
   <fils1 id=2>context1</fils1>
  </el1>
  <el2>
   <fils1 id=1>context2</fils1>
   <fils2>test2</fils2>
   <fils1 id=2>context2</fils1>
  </el2>
  <el3>...........
   <fils1 id=3>context1</fils1>
  <el3>
</Racine>
```

Conerning the node "**fils2**" in "**el1**" and "**el2**", the contain is different, then i want to keep them unchange and when not, i want to add an id number to make the difference.

Comment: Please, edit the question and provide the exact wanted output.

Comment: If `<fils1>context1</fils1>` also occurred under the **el2** element, would you also count this as a duplicate? (i.e Does the parent element make a difference to the duplicate check).

Comment: Hi Tim C, thanks for your remark. As you asked, when a <fils1>context1</fils1> also occured in **el2**, it would be considered as duplicate, but in this case, the content of this node in **el2** is different from the content in **el1**(context2#context1).You can look the expected output for more details.Thanks

Comment: Is the input document unstructured? Or do the elements to be tested for commonality always occur at the same (3rd) level? Do these elements always have names like fils1, fils2 etc? or can they be any name?

Comment: The document is structured and the elements have to be tested for the whole document then they can occur every where under the elements names like el1, el2, etc... The name of to be tested elements are always fils1, fils2, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This XSLT 1.0 style-sheet...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:key name="kCommon" match="*[starts-with(name(),'fils')]"
                        use="concat(name(),'|',.)" />

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(),'fils')]
                      [count(key('kCommon',concat(name(),'|',.))) >= 2]">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    <xsl:variable name="this-key" select="concat(name(),'|',.)" />
    <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="
      count(preceding::*
             [starts-with(name(),'fils')]
             [count(.|key('kCommon',$this-key)) =
              count(  key('kCommon',$this-key))    ]
            ) + 1" /></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>  

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

...will transform this input...

```
<Racine>
  <el1>
   <fils1>context1</fils1>
   <fils2>test1</fils2>
   <fils1>context1</fils1>
  </el1>
  <el2>
   <fils1>context2</fils1>
   <fils2>test2</fils2>
   <fils1>context2</fils1>
  </el2>
  <el3>
   <fils1>context1</fils1>
  </el3>
</Racine>
```

...into...

```
<Racine>
  <el1>
    <fils1 id="1">context1</fils1>
    <fils2>test1</fils2>
    <fils1 id="2">context1</fils1>
  </el1>
  <el2>
    <fils1 id="1">context2</fils1>
    <fils2>test2</fils2>
    <fils1 id="2">context2</fils1>
  </el2>
  <el3>
    <fils1 id="3">context1</fils1>
  </el3>
</Racine>
```

### Explanation

We build a key ('kCommon') of the fils elements that have both common name and common text content. We look for elements which have membership in thier key group of at least two - in other words filX type elements that have a name and text in common with at least one other filX element. This is our last template.

For each such common element, we build two sets:

1. The set of all preceding fil elements in the common group. This set is given by...

   #### Set 1

   ```
   preceding::*[starts-with(name(),'fils')]
   ```
2. And this node's common name+content group, which is...

   #### Set 2

   ```
   key('kCommon',concat(name(),'|',.))
   ```

   But because we will reference concat(name(),'|',.) quiet a few times, and in places where we don't have direct access to this context node, we just compute the concat() and substitute into Set 2 like this. Set 2 is now quick to compute.

   #### Set 2

   ```
   key('kCommon',$this-key)
   ```
3. And then we take a set intersection using the [Kaysian method](http://sources.redhat.com/ml/xsl-list/2000-08/msg00355.html).

   ```
    $set1[count(.|$set2)=count($set2)]
   ```
4. This intersection is the set of all like-minded element to this one that preceded it. We just count them up and add one, and this gives us an ordinal for the id property.

Comment: Hi Sean. Thanks for this code. It walks very well. But i see that you have concatenated the node **fils1** in the element **el3** with the element **el2**. I want to keep this node in the element **el3** so to get the following output:

     `<el2>
       <fils1 id="1">context2</fils1>
       <fils2>test2</fils2>
       <fils1 id="2">context2</fils1>
     </el2>
     <el3>
       <fils1 id="3">context1</fils1>
     </el3>`

Comment: All is ok now.it walks now fine.Thanks for your help.